# Differential capacitive transducer

Tags: differential, capacitive, transducer

I would like to design a differential capacitive transducer to measure the capacitance change in an accelerometer.

[image]

I cant seem to understand, how to demodulate the signal and keep the actual DC value. If you have any suggestion please help.

Comment: R4 seems a bit "low" (to be verified in simulation). For demodulating, "peak" is a bit non-linear. So, choose a sample/hold circuit, or an I-Q demodulator.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to design a differential capacitive transducer to measure the capacitance change in an accelerometer.

Here is what happens with a higher value of your "R4".
No amplifier was used (necessary for the high input impedance).

EE&O.
[image]

UPDATE: **Be aware that sensor "capacitors" are really very "low". See Cref value**.
So, the "output" capacitor must be taken into account (here, from **0.1 pF to 1 pF, step x2**).

[image]

Here is an example circuit for measuring (in some cases), the amplitude of a modulated wave in one "half cycle".  It can be adapted for your case easily.
X2 (comparator) and nearest components (C5, L1) are used for sampling Vm input at "max", followed by "timer" pulses of 20ns, driving the "samplers" (switches wired as OR switches sampling @ each "half" cycle).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to measure capacitance you can use a Sauty bridge.This will convert the change in capacitance to a small AC signal which then you can rectify with filter and from then use a ADC to convert the analog signal to binary form.